# How to implement interfaces for dialog created from android binding from a XML?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I have an Android binding for a XML called `dialog_volume_all.xml` which is a layout. So its binding is called `DialogVolumeAllBinding`. I'm inflating it like this:

```
DialogVolumeAllBinding dialogVolumeAllBinding = DialogVolumeAllBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this));
```

and I'm creating a dialog from it as

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context, R.style.MyDialogTheme);
AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
alert.setView(dialogVolumeAllBinding);
```

However I also want to implement `public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)  {` on my dialog.

How can I implement things on a dialog from a binding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before setting the view to dialog, create a variable view and initialize it with dialogVolumeAllBinding.root which returns the root view.

`View root = dialogVolumeAllBinding.root;`

Now you can implement onTouchListener or any other interface on this root view.

`root.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
// your code
});`